# speed up selenium webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

have a simple selenium script used to check if a username is available or not, here the code

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
username = 'test'
driver.navigate.to url
fn = driver.find_element(:id, "first-name")
fn.send_keys "bla"
ln = driver.find_element(:id, "last-name")
ln.send_keys "bla"
un = driver.find_element(:id, "user-name")
un.send_keys username
p = driver.find_element(:id, "password")
p.click
sleep 3
if driver.find_element(:id=>"user-name-validation-message").text.include? "This username is not available."
    puts "#{username} is good"
end
```

it works fine but it need lot of time to be executed, most of it to start firefox each time, I was wondering if there is a way to execute it in background or if there are any kind of trick to speed up this proccess.
Suppose i have to check 100 usernames, i need tons of time.
Thank you

Comment: If you dont want the browser to show up, you could use HTMLdriver instead of Firefox. This will run in the background without any browser

Comment: Using `sleep` will slow down your script. Presumably you want to use an explicit wait instead. This would allow you to only wait the needed amount of time rather than always 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTMLUnit Driver or PhantomJS to execute Headless
Consider using Implicity wait and PageToLoad, ScriptToLoad or Fluent Wait with your Instantiated webdriver.